# In place randomized selection algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, selection

We are currently studying algorithms hence I marked this question as “homework” even though this is not a homework related task. Just to be safe.

We just studied the randomized selection algorithm, and the logic seems simple. Choose an element from a list, and then put the element in its right place. Then repeat the process in one sub list until the element at the index is in its place. Where index is the position of the element you want in the sort list.

This should be a modified version of the quick sort algorithm. But we only sort one sub list, not both sub lists. Hence a performance boost (in big-oh).

I can successfully implement this algorithm using external storage (C++, and zero based array’s):

```
int r_select2(vector<int>& list, int i)
{
   int p = list[0];

   vector<int> left, right;

   for (int k = 1; k < list.size(); ++k)
   {
      if (list[k] < p)  left.push_back(list[k]);
      else     right.push_back(list[k]);
   }

   int j = left.size();

   if (j > i) p = r_select2(left, i);
   else if (j < i) p = r_select2(right, i - j - 1);

   return p;
}
```

However, I want to implement the algorithm using in-situ (in-place), and not use extra sub arrays. I believe that this should be an easy/trivial task. But somewhere, my in-situ version goes wrong. Maybe it’s just late and I need to sleep, but I can’t see the root cause of why the following version fails:

```
int r_select(vector<int>& list, int begin, int end, int i)
{
   i = i + begin;
   int p = list[begin];

   if (begin < end)
   {
      int j = begin;
      for (int k = begin + 1; k < end; ++k)
      {
         if (list[k] < p)
         {
            ++j;
            swap(list[j], list[k]);
         }
      }

      swap(list[begin], list[j]);

      if (j > i) p = r_select(list, begin, j, i);
      else if (j < i) p = r_select(list, j + 1, end, i - j);
   }

   return p;
}
```

In both examples, the first element is being used as the pivot to keep the design simple. In both example, `i` is the index of the element I want.

Any ideas where the 2nd example is failing? Is it a simple off-by-one error?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs, the output you get, and the output you expect?

Comment: Input list might contain numbers 0 to 99 in a random order. Upon a calling `r_select(list, 0, list.size(), 88)`, I expect 88 to be returned.

Comment: @PinkDuck: And what does your implementation provide? a failing test case can help reviewers understand where the mistake is

Comment: Example: list = 3, 8, 4, 6, 1, 0. Calling r_select(list, 0, list.size(), 3); Expected: 4. Actual: 6.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds fishy:

```
i = i + begin;
...
r_select(list, begin, j, i);
```